# Reinstall Typo3 instead of upgrade

Tags: typo3, upgrade, migrate, templavoila

I have an old Typo3 installation which was upgraded many times before. At the moment it's at version 4.5.
Because I had several severe problems upgrading, I am thinking of setting up a clean Typo3 6.2 LTS setup and migrate the pages, instead of upgrading again.

My question is now, what is the best way to transfer the pages as well as the calendar, news and TemplaVoila from version 4.5 to version 6.2? I have more than 1000 pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade a TYPO3 4.5 website to TYPO3 6.2 as soon as all extensions used in TYPO3 4.5 are compatible with TYPO3 6.2. I think this will still take some weeks until the major extensions are provided with an update for TYPO3 6.2

If you dont want to wait, you can try to use the patches named in the [smooth migration wiki](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-smoothmigration/wiki)

At least, there is a patch for tt_news.

In case of TemplaVoila you can try using this [version](https://github.com/wouter90/templavoila) which could be compatible with TYPO3 6.2

In case you do not know: The TemplaVoila extension will not be maintained any more (more details about that [here](http://blog.tolleiv.de/2013/06/templavoila-future/)), so it is not very future safe to use it on a TYPO3 6.2 website.

If you want to use FluidTemplate and Grid Elements instead of TemplaVoila, you can try to use my extension [tv2fluidge](https://github.com/derhansen/sf_tv2fluidge) to migrate your TYPO3 4.5 website to FluidTemplate and Grid Elements. This is of course a lot of work (creating new page templates and Grid Elementes), but you can keep your page structure and content and do not have to wait for an TYPO3 6.2 version of TemplaVoila.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will be work for 100% but you can copy all tables with prefix tt_news, calendar etc. and pastle them to new db. If you have some images and other files you will find it in uploads/tx_ttnews/ - you should copy it too. I don't use TemplaVoila so I don't know how to move that to another site. And you have to remember about `pid` and `id` of pages/ce - they have to be the same